# Return false click attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code in my view page, when the user clicks on this button I want the browser to stay in place (not reload to the top).

```
<%= button_tag '<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>'.html_safe, class: "btn btn-success", remote: true %>
```

I'm using the click attribute to keep the user in the same place

```
$(function() {
  $('#icon-thumbs-up').click(function() {
   return false;
  });
});
```

I'm new to Javascript/JQuery so I realize I am probably botching this code pretty badly, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just a tip: don't use `return false`. Use `event.preventDefault()` (while passing `event` as a parameter to the click handle function like so: `function(event){ event.preventDefault(); .....`

Answer (score 3):

This selector in your code:

`$('#icon-thumbs-up')`

is for an ID.

You've got a class assigned to the button, so change the selector as below:

```
$(function() {
    $('.icon-thumbs-up').click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Your selector is an ID selector but you don't have an ID of that name in your markup. (You do have a class with that name, but a class selector begins with a `.` not a `#`).
2. You are generating your button using some template function, and including an `<i>` element inside it. It is that `<i>` element you are trying to prevent the default behaviour of, not the button. You need to adjust your code to target whatever HTML is generated for the button itself.

Comment: Thanks, even making those adjustments it still doesn't work, I tried putting a <div> with an id around that line and called on that id in the javascript but it still isn't recognizing the javascript

Comment: So you stopped targeting the `<i>`, wrapped the whole thing with a `<div>` and targeted that? You need to target **the button**.